# Groups in group on routing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing

I really need help!

On the Laravel 5.3, it seems that a group of routes into an another group isn't working for me. Is there any solution to make it work ? Or do I have to write my routes in another way ? This is the way I write my routes:

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]
],
function()
{
Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'admin'
    ], function () {

    // General Settings
    Route::get('settings', [
        'as' => 'admin.settings',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@showSettings'
    ]);
});

});
```

I am using a prefix in the first group for the multiple language and the another group is for the admin section. I want an url like this : `/en/admin/settings`

Comment: What `LaravelLocalization::setLocale()` returns?

Comment: Its return the language selected in default. I use https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved! It did not work because I had used another route in which there was an paramater before the group of admin section ex:

```
Route::get('activate/{code}', [
    'as' => 'auth.activation',
    'uses' => 'RegistrationController@getActivate'
]);
```